# Get voltage at power suply from ubuntu virtual server

Tags: 14.04

I need to know current voltage at power suply in Ubuntu. I am noob soo I google it and I found command like this

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/voltage_now
```

But there is no file or other directory in my "/sys/class/power_supply/" directory.

I will be greatful for any advice

```
acpitool -B
```

shows " Battery status : "

Comment: Only one line " Battery status : <not available>".

Comment: Wait. "ubuntu virtual server"?  That will not have a battery(?)

Comment: I have this as a school project... There have to be a way how to find it...

Comment: Only if the virtualized environment makes it available. I can think of almost zero reason to do that, as it doesn't matter to a virtual machine - and might theoretically leak information to the VM. So the short answer is that you probably can't, inside the VM.

Comment: Your answer cant satisfited ne :D i only got adress to virtual server and order to do it.. I am not first student who is solving this... It have to work..